# Chat Server with Netty

Tags: java, networking, netty

I wrote a simple chat server with netty, a friend and I have been testing it with telnet. When both of us are connected, it says the size of the group is 1. Whenever writing to the list of users, it only writes to whoever sent the message. How can I fix this?

```
import org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.Channel;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelStateEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.MessageEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroup;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup;

public class ServerChannelHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

  private ChannelGroup users = new DefaultChannelGroup();

  @Override
  public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
    users.write(e.getMessage());
  }

  @Override
  public void channelOpen(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
    users.add(e.getChannel());
    System.out.println("Opened. ");
    System.out.println(users.size());
  }

  @Override
  public void channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
    users.remove(e.getChannel());
  }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must share the same instance of the handler for all created ChannelPipeline instances. Or declare the ChannelGroup as static final

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that.. Thank you, I was creating a new ChannelHandler whenever a channel would connect.